# how to remove duplicate records but need to keep their child table rows and tag them to survived row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

can you please help me in writing the query for both table
database : sql server

master_table

```
primary  name
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   b
5   b
6   c
7   c


foreign
key 
reference 
above table

1   aa
2   aaa
3   aaaa
4   bb
5   bbb
6   cc
7   ccc
```

### expected output

now I need to remove duplicate from above table based upon name
after removing duplicates name

master_table

```
primary  name
1             a
4             b
6             c
```

to remove duplicate records but need to keep their child table rows and tag them to survived row

```
foreign
key 
reference 
above table
fk      name_city
1   aa
1   aaa
1   aaaa
4   bb
4   bbb
6   cc
6   ccc
```

---

can you please help me in writing the query for both table
        database : sql server

---

**Thanks Gordon Linoff for reply**

Let me add more detail
how I think it can be done

added rownum to master_table based upon  duplicated on name

```
primary  name   row_num
1      a    1
2      a    2
3      a    3

4      b    1
5      b    2

6      c    1
7      c    2
```

---

```
foreign
key 
reference 
above 
table
fk  name_city      (map_name             |get primarykey from above 
                   based                 | table with joining condition
                   upon                  |map_name=name
                  matching               |and rownum = 1)
                  fk
                  with
                 primary )
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   aa      a                               1
2   aaa     a                               1
3   aaaa    a                               1

4   bb      b                                 4
5   bbb     b                                 4

6   cc      c                               6
7   ccc     c                               6
```

Please suggest if this is the right way
Thanks a lot for your time and kind

Comment: can you please verify the below query is the same what I am expecting. select mt.minid, name_city
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by name) as minid
      from master_table t
     ) mt join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t.id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #master (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50)); --DROP TABLE #master
INSERT INTO #master VALUES (1, 'a')
INSERT INTO #master VALUES (2, 'a')
INSERT INTO #master VALUES (3, 'a')
INSERT INTO #master VALUES (4, 'b')
INSERT INTO #master VALUES (5, 'b')
INSERT INTO #master VALUES (6, 'c')
INSERT INTO #master VALUES (7, 'c')

-- create temporary mapping table
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT ID, MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS [MinID]
   FROM #master
)
SELECT *
INTO #TempMapping -- DROP TABLE #TempMapping
FROM cte
WHERE cte.ID <> cte.MinID;

-- check to make sure that the IDs mapped as expected
SELECT * FROM #TempMapping;

-- change FKed values to their respective MIN mappings
UPDATE nc
SET nc.fk = tmp.MinID
FROM name_city nc
INNER JOIN #TempMapping tmp
        ON tmp.ID = nc.fk;

-- remove non-MIN IDs from master now that nothing references them
DELETE mstr
FROM   #master mstr
INNER JOIN #TempMapping tmp
        ON tmp.ID = mstr.ID;
```

If there are *a lot* of rows in the [name_city] table or concurrency issues (i.e. blocking), then the #TempMapping table should probably be a real table (e.g. "dbo.TempMasterMappings") instead of a temp table. At that point, you can do this one ID at a time in a loop to keep the transactions smaller and quicker. Just replace the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries above with the following (which can even be run from a stored procedure). This method will work for any number of millions of rows (assuming that there is an index on the [fk] field, which there should be anyway).

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT; -- this can be an input param for a proc
SET @BatchSize = 5000;

DECLARE @CurrentIDtoChange INT,
        @CurrentNewID INT;

BEGIN TRY

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN

  SELECT TOP (1)
         @CurrentIDtoChange = map.ID,
         @CurrentNewID = map.MinID
  FROM   dbo.TempMasterMappings map
  ORDER BY map.ID ASC;

  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.TempMasterMappings; -- clean up!
    BREAK; -- exit outer loop
  END;

  WHILE (1 = 1)
  BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) nc
    SET    nc.fk = @CurrentNewID
    FROM   dbo.name_city nc
    WHERE  nc.fk = @CurrentIDtoChange
    OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN);

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
      DELETE mstr -- clean up PK record
      FROM   dbo.[Master] mstr
      WHERE  mstr.ID = @CurrentIDtoChange;

      DELETE tmm -- remove ID as it is fully migrated!
      FROM   dbo.TempMasterMappings tmm
      WHERE  tmm.ID = @CurrentIDtoChange;
      BREAK; -- exit inner loop
    END;
END;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
  RAISERROR(@Message, 16, 1);
END CATCH;
```

Comment: ThankYou very much for your effort and help. I appreciate your help srutzky .

Comment: for 43 million records it will take 43 days :( . its  processing 1 million records per day.

Comment: @user3380585 : what is your BatchSize value? do you have an index on the fk field? have you rebuilt the index recently, or at least done an UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULL SCAN?

Comment: batchsize is 1 million. I created index on joining fields. I created index on TempMasterMappings.ID. size of this TempMasterMappings is 43 million  .  Table dbo.name_city is having 100 million records. dbo.[Master]  table is 120 million.

Comment: @user3380585 those table sizes would have been really helpful to have at the start. That info is critical to getting a good answer and should have been in the question. I need to go to sleep now but can update in the morning with a change that should fix it. For now I can say that the batch size is way too many...try a few values between 5k and maybe 30k to see what works best. .

Comment: I have 64GB ram . and its processing 600 records per minute. tested for batch-size 5k,25k,50k,950k  throughput is 600 records per minute for all size .

Comment: thanks a  lot. you are a Gem. its 1300 records per minutes with batch size 2.  Can you tell me why?

Comment: @user3380585 you beat me to the update. I had meant to update my answer with the suggestion and explanation but got busy. I will still do that later. It has to do with the row counts you provided last night: with 100 million rows in the target and 43 million in the source, that means on avg 2 rows per source ID to update. AND not all target rows need updating. So instead of telling SQL Server to look for 5000 records that don't exist, we target the 1 or 2 that do. That makes better use of the index as well. I still think you should try a BatchSize of 1. Might be ever better than 2 :).

Comment: @user3380585 is the job still running? If so, there is another thing to do to get this type of operation to run faster.

Comment: Hey Srutzky,  Thanks a lot for update. Will you please suggest me some other way. I am thinking to rebuild tables, with adding columns to tables and populate columns by join(update). Then I can do it in a single sql.

Comment: @user3380585 Please go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65987/how-to-remove-duplicate-records-but-need-to-keep-their-child-table-rows-and-tag-t

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace all the ids in the second table with the minimum matching id in the first, if I understand correctly.

This query should return the result set you want:

```
select mt.minid, name_city
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by name) as minid
      from master_table t
     ) mt join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t.id;
```

It is unclear from the question whether you just want to get the right output, or whether you want to modify the tables.  Updating the tables would basically be changing the above `select` to a similar `update` query and then deleting the extra rows from the master table.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gorden . It would  you great if you please review the question I edited

Comment: @user3380585 . . . If you want the additional columns, just add them into the outer `select`.  I assume that your values for rows 6 and 7 are typos.

Comment: yup typo inadvertently. Thanks a lot. I edited again.

Comment: 1)step 1 : I will add row_num to master_table  2) step 2 : I will add column to table 2 and  copy the name column from table 1 (based upon joining Foreign key  3) step 3 : I will add another column in table 2 , I will use this column to map the primary key of master_table having row_num =1 ..... Is this a right approch?

Comment: I will modify tables . I will remove duplicates from master_table .  Also I need to remap the foreign keys to the surviving rows ( that is having row_num = 1. Then in the last I will delete rows from above column having row_num> 2

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Gorden. I appreciate it.